# Excel prevent duplicates in column error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I create a new excel sheet. I insert a couple of values in column a. Then I select the entire A column for data validation. As a formula I type in:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1
```

But then Excel tells me: There's a problem with this formula.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After values are in column **A**, select only **A1** for data validation *(not the whole column)* and apply your formula to it.

Then copy the *DV* downwards.

Comment: @Hillcow Does your version of Excel use ***,*** or ***;*** for the separator ??

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much! Unbelievable. I looked at around 10 tutorials and not a single one mentioned this.

Comment: @Hillcow Don't forget to accept Gary's answer given it solves your issue.

Comment: I didn't accept because the answer is here in the comments and not the actual reply. But I guess that works too.